# Storing login name and password if condition is met

Tags: php, session, cookies, passwords

After a successful login, I would like to store the username in a cookie and if the user has been marked in a database as being an admin, I would like it to store both the username and password somehow, I have read that storing the password in a cookie is insecure, but how else can it be done. This is for a jQuery mobile website. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jamesil/4VAJc/ This is what I have so far which currently stores both the username and password and uses js. Maybe this needs to be done in PHP?
Currently if I want to show something just to the admin, I wrap whatever it is in this

```
<?php 
$is_admin=(isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['is_admin_flag']) && $_SESSION['is_admin_flag']=='t');
?>
Some code
<?php } ?>
```

Any feedback is much appreciated, also Im very new to PHP.
Cheers

Comment: why you want to store username and password of admin in cookie, its a dangerous thing to do.

Comment: i assume for extended sessions, which would go into a database of course.

Comment: what for you need to store password? Generate a random number, memorize it in a session and in the cookie. and then compare it to reject break-in attempts

Comment: You should not be storing plaintext passwords anywhere, even if it's in a session.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback and when I say admin, i mean its a user that has more options after logging in. It doesn't have to be a cookie, The admin just needs to have the password stored somehow, so when they go to the login screen it automatically fills out the fields so all they have to do is click on login

Comment: Anyway, you did not point a **good** reason to save a password in a cookie

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing the password on the client side is a very insecure practice, what you should you is generate a token on the server side. I mean a unique identifier using any cryptografic algorithm i.e( `md5`, `sha1`, `sha256`).

For example, create a token using the username and password info concatenated plus some random info:

```
md5($_SESSION['username'] . $_SESSION['password'] . time() . microtime())
```

Then, store this token on the database and save this token on the user cookies.

This token is a proof that the user is already authenticated. So, after that, on the client side, every request should send the token in the `http` headers or any other places, and on the backend, it will be compared with the one sorted on the db.

If they match, then you are sure that the request come from the right guy.

**Another thing, make the token expire after some time (may be 30 minutes) after the last request.**